# What is this approach to database updating called?

Tags: database

Say I have a set of objects in my database: `{A, B, C, D}`

Now, business logic has generated a new list `{A, B, E, F}` and needs to update the old one:

Two options present themselves:

1)

- Remove the entire list `{A, B, C, D}`
- Insert the entire list `{A, B, E, F}`

2)

- Calculate the items that are no longer needed: `{C, D}`
- Calculate the items that need to be added: `{E, F}`
- remove `{C, D}`
- insert `{E, F}`

Now, naturally one of these approaches puts more load on the DB, and the other puts more load on the client.

My question is, what are these two approaches called? (Read: What can I refer to them as in an email and have the other person understand and/or Google it and get sensible, clarifying explanations?)

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question! But I also find it hard to find anything for the first approach, sth. like `Insert Update` or `Delete Reinsert Update` would come to my mind but those do not seem to be popular names for that (maybe there isn't one at all), the second approach though clearly seems to be a `Differential Update`

Comment: 'Differential Update' is enough to meet my needs. Perfect, Thank you very much!